# How to Configure UrlRewritingNet on asp.net web application client end

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, web.config-transform

Please am fairly new to programming in asp.net and now am following the steps in a textbook to design an e-commerce web application.

I am using UrlRewritingNet dll from http://www.urlrewriting.net/ to create search engine friendly urls on the application. I unzipped the urlrewritingnet zip and copied its dll file to my application's bin folder. I also copied its urlrewritingnet.xsd file to my project folder. The textbook am working from uses the dll from urlrewriter.net with different configurations which I tried in my project but it didn't work. The textbook also uses visual web developer 2005. Am programming in visual studio 2012 (C#). For now am trying to rewrite the url of my catalogs page so as to test if the configuration in my web.config file is correct. I'm doing the configuration in my web.config, not in IIS. I do not want any IIS configurations because am imagining a scenario where I don't have access to the server.

I keep getting an internal server error that displays like this:

HTTP Error 500.22 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.

this is the url which I want to rewrite:  http://localhost:1036/Catalog.aspx?DepartmentID=1

**This is my config file:**

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="urlrewritingnet"
    restartOnExternalChanges="true"
    requirePermission ="false"
    type="UrlRewritingNet.Configuration.UrlRewriteSection, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter" />
  </configSections>
  <urlrewritingnet
    rewriteOnlyVirtualUrls="true"
    contextItemsPrefix="QueryString"
    defaultProvider = "RegEx"
    defaultPage = "Default.aspx"
    xmlns="http://www.urlrewriting.net/schemas/config/2006/07" >
    <rewrites>
      <add name="Rule1"
      provider="RegEx"
      virtualUrl="^.*-d([0-9]+)/?$"
      rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
      destinationUrl="~/Catalog.aspx?DepartmentID=$1"
      ignoreCase="true" />
    </rewrites>
  </urlrewritingnet>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MailServer" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
    <add key="MailUsername" value="engr.ejikeeze@gmail.com"/>
    <add key="MailPassword" value="keeplooking"/>
    <add key="MailFrom" value="engr.ejikeeze@gmail.com"/>
    <add key="EnableErrorLogEmail" value="false"/>
    <add key="ErrorLogEmail" value="engr.ejikeeze@gmail.com"/>
    <add key="ProductsPerPage" value="6"/>
    <add key="ProductDescriptionLength" value="60"/>
    <add key="SiteName" value="BalloonShop"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BalloonShopConnection" connectionString="server = (local)\SQLEXPRESS; Database = BalloonShop; User = balloonshop; password=ecommerce" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="UrlRewriteModule"
      type="UrlRewritingNet.Web.UrlRewriteModule, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter" />
    </httpModules>
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-US"/>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="Oops.aspx" />
    <pages theme="BalloonShopDefault">
      <controls>
        <add src="~/UserControls/DepartmentsList.ascx" tagName="DepartmentsList" tagPrefix="BSUC"/>
    </controls>
    </pages>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Pls I need you lovely guys to help me out. Am really stuck. I've searched all round the internet for over 4 days in search of solution but to no avail. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the following link:[url-rewriting-in-Asp-Net](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/akkiraju/url-rewriting-in-Asp-Net/)

Comment: The examples in the site use switch case to rewrite urls. When my application gets large and I have so many urls to rewrite, this approach wont be robust enough for my application, besides, the rewriting is done in the business layer which would warrant pulling down site, recompiling and redeploying should I want to make any tweaks later. I need something I would handle in my web.config or in an external xml file which I could link to, this is why I chose to use the assembly from urlrewritingnet.net. thanks all the same.